# Postman - How to sent .json file as POST data payload within pre-request scrpt?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

For the purpose of my testing, I need to fetch `.json` file at `pre-request script` section and use it as payload for POST request using Postman, then once been fetched need to alter some data on it.

My `.json` looks like:

```
{
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "password": "Abc12345",
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
 }
```

After being fetched, I need to change email address with another dynamically generated email.

*I know its possible to use .json file within `body -> binary` section of Postman, but this is not sufficient for the use-case that I need.*
[image]

Is there any way to **fetch** .json file with-in pre-request script and then **alter** a value befere firing the request?

Comment: As per my understanding, we send files which means we have to upload them as binary. and if it is a JSON then just send it as an object (JSON.stringify).

Comment: I was wondering is it possible to be fetched somehow from pre-request script? If not, then how to use this binary file into the pre-request section? This is what I am after